# Iterate through maven project's dependency jars with eclipse-resource-api (plugin development)

Tags: java, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, m2eclipse

I have a maven project. And i want to iterate through its dependency jar projects and read some property files in them.
With eclipse resource api, i can get an IProject instance in workspace and access its classpath file.

Class-path has the following structure.

```
    <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.m2e.MAVEN2_CLASSPATH_CONTAINER">
        <attributes>
            <attribute name="maven.pomderived" value="true"/>
            <attribute name="org.eclipse.jst.component.nondependency" value=""/>
        </attributes>
    </classpathentry>
```

How can i extract the actual dependency jar locations from this?

i was expecting something like this instead

```
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/apache-xerces/xercesImpl/2.9.1/xercesImpl-2.9.1.jar"/>
 <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/apache-xerces/xml-apis/2.9.1/xml-apis-2.9.1.jar"/>
</classpath>
```

2.Or is there any better approach than this to read through maven dependency jars programatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getResolvedClasspath` method of `IJavaProject` deals with resolving containers:

```
IProject project = ... get project

IJavaProject javaProject = JavaCore.create(project);

IClasspathEntry[] classPathEntries = javaProject.getResolvedClasspath(true);
```

The JavaDoc says:

> This is a helper method returning the resolved classpath for the
> project as a list of simple (non-variable, non-container) classpath
> entries. All classpath variable and classpath container entries in the
> project's raw classpath will be replaced by the simple classpath
> entries they resolve to.

Comment: Seems that's the way to proceed. Will try this.Thanks.

Comment: Hi,Is it possible to access files inside classpath entries (dependency jars) as IFile instance. ? The classpath entries are not actually inside workspace isn't it . In my case, my interested one is inside my local maven repo jar. What is the best approach to access that file as IFile?

Comment: Or else a way to access that dependency jar as IProject?

Comment: If they aren't in the workspace you can't access them as IFiles or IProject.

Comment: In that case, Do u know how we could access the files inside classpath Entries(jar files)?I tried to do this but didn't work.           `for (IClasspathEntry classpathEntry: classPathEntries) { 
     InputStream is = classpathEntry.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/Packages.xml");}`

Comment: i was able to get that. Thanks.

Comment: `IClasspathEntry` has a `getPath()` method to return the `IPath` of the jar. `IPath` has  `toFile()` to get a `File` or `toOSString()` to get the path string.